# Testing concurrency with Thread.new in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, postgresql, rspec

I'm trying to set up a test around concurrency. The end goal is to test that a service using ActiveRecord [`skips locked` records in PostgreSQL](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/what-is-select-skip-locked-for-in-postgresql-9-5/).

This works great in two consoles:

```
# in console 1
queue = MyFancyQueue.first
item_1 = queue.items.first
item_1.with_lock { sleep 30 } # locks item_1 for 30 seconds

# in console 2, while item_1 is locked
queue = MyFancyQueue.first
queue.items.first # => item_1
queue.items.lock('FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED').first # => item_2
```

However, with RSpec, any code I run in a `Thread.new` can't find any record, something like:

```
let(:queue) { MyFancyQueue.create }
let!(:items) { create_list(:item, 2, queue: queue) }

context 'with first item locked' do
  it 'returns the second item' do
    Thread.new { queue.items.first.with_lock { sleep 30 } }

    expect(queue.items.lock('FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED').first).to eq items.last
  end
end
```

would throw an error saying `queue.items.first` can't be found, and when using `pry` to look into the thread, I can't see any items.

How do I effectively test something like this with RSpec?

Comment: is `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` in your rails_helper.rb?

Comment: @OlegSobchuk it's set to true

Comment: change to `false` and try once more

Answer (score 2):

If you use `DatabaseCleaner` make sure `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation` for this test.